# Keyboard switched to Arabic

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Hello I am very concerned. I was just typing characters into google and my computer lagged a little bit and changed to arabic for a solid minute. I was trying to figure out what keys I pressed to cause this or it just happened on its own. After that minute the computer lagged and it switched back to english. Is there some computer shortcut that does this language switching or should I be concerned that someone out there is monitoring my use of this computer? FYI, I have a thnkpad t410 and on Ubuntu 16.04 loving it :).

Comment: Do you mean language (the language of the words displayed on the screen - if yes, what components did change? Ubuntu controls? Specific applications? Browser content?) or keyboard layout?

Comment: They keyboard was typing Arabic letters and they were showing on the screen @ByteCommander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably accidentally hit the keyboard shortcut to cycle through your configured keyboard layouts, which is by default <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> if I remember correctly.

Go to **System Settings → Text Entry** to view and change the relevant configuration:

[image: text entry settings screenshot]

You can remove the shortcuts in the right column or you can remove all keyboard layouts which you don't want to use from the input sources list in the left column.

Comment: Is the super key the Windows key?

Comment: Yes, it is. We just don't like to call it that way. ;-)